# Where to put the google-services.json file for Firebase in netbeans?

Tags: maven, firebase, netbeans-8

Can somebody help with where to put the google-services.json file I downloaded from Firebase? I'm using maven in netbeans? Or is there some other way of doing it without the file?

Answer (score 0):

The only supported way to work with Firebase on Android is using the Gradle plugin, as described in [the setup documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).  You can't build an app with Firebase using only maven, unless you do all the work that would be done by the plugin to properly [inject the values from your google-services.json](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) file into your app build, or skip that and initialize Firebase yourself.

Comment: Ok in maven I don't know where to put the Gradle plugin, or which one the app module is. So about initializing it myself, If I put "FirebaseOptions options = new Firebaseoptions.Builder()" I can only use like .setCredential() , .setDatabseUrl() , .build() and a few others, but I've seen examples of where they use something like .setProjectId() or some others. But if I put that it it gives me error and says "cannot find symbol". So do I need some other dependencies or what?